# Dataset entry are longer than x axis in MpAndroid chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Am trying to create BarChart (grouped DataSets) chart using mpandroid chart while am setting values using real time data from sqlite however whenver i fetch data from webservice and trying to set value to Chart am getting error like Dataset Entry are longer than x axis values of chartdata object 
Here is my code:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import SqliteDatabase.TimeTrackerDAO;
import model.DashboardModelCommercial;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 27-06-2016.
 */
public class DashBoardCommercial extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    RequestQueue mrequestqueue;
    TimeTrackerDAO timeTrackerDAO;
    private int dashboard = 1;
    Cursor c;
    List<DashboardModelCommercial>listobj;
    View   view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_commercial, container, false);

        BarChart chart = (BarChart)view. findViewById(R.id.chart);
        timeTrackerDAO=new TimeTrackerDAO(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        listobj=new ArrayList<>();

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(dashboard, null, this);
        return view;
    }



    /*private ArrayList<IBarDataSet> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);
        BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet1.add(v1e6);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet2.add(v2e1);
        BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet2.add(v2e2);
        BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet2.add(v2e3);
        BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet2.add(v2e4);
        BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet2.add(v2e5);
        BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet2.add(v2e6);


        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet3 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v2e= new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet3.add(v2e);
        BarEntry v = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet3.add(v);
        BarEntry vv = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet3.add(vv);
        BarEntry vvv = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet3.add(vvv);
        BarEntry vvvv = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet3.add(vvvv);
        BarEntry vvvvv = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet3.add(vvvvv);

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(valueSet3, "Brand 3");
        barDataSet3.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet3);
        return dataSets;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("JAN");
        xAxis.add("FEB");
        xAxis.add("MAR");
        xAxis.add("APR");
        xAxis.add("MAY");
        xAxis.add("JUN");
        return xAxis;
    }
*/
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getContext().getApplicationContext(), TimeTrackerDAO.DB_Timetracker_DashBoardCommercial, null, null, null, null){

            ForceLoadContentObserver mObserver=new ForceLoadContentObserver();
            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground() {


                c = timeTrackerDAO.DashBoardCommercial();
                if(c==null){
                    Log.d("No Data", "No Data");
                }

                else  {
                    c.getCount();
                    c.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
                    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), getUri());

                }
                return c;
            }




        };


    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        BarChart chart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        if (getDataSet(data)
                != null) {

            BarData data_commercial = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet(data));
            chart.setData(data_commercial);
            chart.setDescription("My Chart");
            chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
            chart.invalidate();
        }

        else {
            Log.e("err", "err");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }


    private ArrayList<IBarDataSet> getDataSet(Cursor c) {
        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;
        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<DashboardModelCommercial>liststatus=new ArrayList<>();

        c=timeTrackerDAO.DashBoardCommercialStatus0();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DashboardModelCommercial dashboardModelCommercial=new DashboardModelCommercial();
                dashboardModelCommercial.setCount(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DashboardModelCommercial.Commercial_Count)));
                liststatus.add(dashboardModelCommercial);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        for(int i=0;i<liststatus.size();i++){
            valueSet1.add(new BarEntry(liststatus.get(i).getCount(),i));//Status 0
        }

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();

        List<DashboardModelCommercial>liststatus1=new ArrayList<>();
        c=timeTrackerDAO.DashBoardCommercialStatus1();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DashboardModelCommercial dashboardModelCommercial=new DashboardModelCommercial();
                dashboardModelCommercial.setCount(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DashboardModelCommercial.Commercial_Count)));
                liststatus1.add(dashboardModelCommercial);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        for(int i=0;i<liststatus1.size();i++){
            valueSet2.add(new BarEntry(liststatus1.get(i).getCount(),i));//Status 0
        }

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet3 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<DashboardModelCommercial>liststatus2=new ArrayList<>();
        c=timeTrackerDAO.DashBoardCommercialStatus2();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                {
                    DashboardModelCommercial dashboardModelCommercial=new DashboardModelCommercial();
                    dashboardModelCommercial.setCount(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DashboardModelCommercial.Commercial_Count)));
                    liststatus2.add(dashboardModelCommercial);
                }
            }while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        for (int i=0;i<liststatus2.size();i++){
            valueSet3.add(new BarEntry(liststatus2.get(i).getCount(),i));
        }

        ArrayList<BarEntry>valueSet4=new ArrayList<>();
        List<DashboardModelCommercial>liststatus3=new ArrayList<>();
        c=timeTrackerDAO.DashBoardCommercialStatus3();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                {
                    DashboardModelCommercial dashboardModelCommercial=new DashboardModelCommercial();
                    dashboardModelCommercial.setCount(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DashboardModelCommercial.Commercial_Count)));
                    liststatus3.add(dashboardModelCommercial);
                }
            }while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        for (int i=0;i<liststatus3.size();i++){
            valueSet4.add(new BarEntry(liststatus3.get(i).getCount(),i));
        }



        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Not Started");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "In Progress");
        barDataSet2.setColor(Color.rgb(164, 228, 251));
        BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(valueSet3, "Completed");
        barDataSet3.setColor(Color.rgb(242, 247, 158));
        BarDataSet barDataSet4 = new BarDataSet(valueSet4, " Not Completed");
        barDataSet4.setColor(Color.rgb(200, 220, 170));


        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet3);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet4);
        return dataSets;
    }
    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("Billable");
        xAxis.add("Non Billable");

        return xAxis;



    }
}
```

I don't know where am making mistake how to recitify if am just banging my head in wall for hours can someone helpme out How to resolve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Bar entries count and XAxis labels count should be equal.
You are adding only 2 XAxis labels in the `getXAxisValues()` method.
May be you are getting more than 2 bar entries in your `BarDataSet`.

Add the XAxis labels that are equal to bar entries count in a `BarDataSet`.

Comment: i know am fetching Bardataset from webservice every times it syncs but Xaxis lables is static so how can i achieve this every time syncs first delete the whole value in sqlite and insert fresh data

Comment: You can add it before creating the `BarData` or add it later like `BarData data = mChart.getData(); data.addXValue("label");` . Please check the line 116 in this [example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/DynamicalAddingActivity.java) on how to add dynamic values to chart.  Off course it is for `LineChart` but it's not that hard to convert to `BarChart`.